# How to prove that length of SCS could be derived from the length of LCS?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Let X[1 . . . m] and Y [1 . . . n] be two given arrays. A common supersequence of X and Y is an array Z[1 . . . k] such that X and Y are both subsequences of Z[1 . . . k]. The goal is to find the shortest common super-sequence (SCS) Z of X and Y, solving the following sub-problems.

How to show that the length k of the array Z satisfies the equation k=m+n−l, where l is the length of the longest common subsequence of X and Y?

Using recurrence equations and induction is required

The answer is pretty logical as I tried to design an algorithm to find the length of SCS.  In order to find the k of Z, we need to find the array that hasXandYas subsequences and is the shortest among all of such arrays.  If we are assured that all elements inXandYare distinct, then we simply can sum the lengths of X and Y.  However, X and Y could have common and repeated elements, we can’t sum the lengths as the task is to find the shortest possible supersequence.  Therefore, we need to consider the longest common subsequence of X and Y and distract it from the sum.

However, I have no idea how to prove it with induction.